# How to set Background image in MasterDetailPage menu

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

How to set Background image in MasterDetailPage menu without **RelativeLayout** and **AbsoluteLayout**.
I also tried with Grid and AbsoluteLayout but it's not working. any solution for this problem?

`BackgroundImageSource="background.png"` is also not working.

My Xaml:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu" BackgroundColor="White"
                 Icon="hamburger.png">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
            <StackLayout x:Name="navigationDrawerList"
                         VerticalOptions="Fill">

                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         Padding="20,0,0,0"
                                         Spacing="20">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       FontSize="Medium"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       TextColor="Gray" />

                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>

            </StackLayout>   
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Padding="50,2,0,2"
                         Spacing="20">

                <Label Text="About Us"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       TextColor="Gray" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Padding="50,2,0,2"
                         Spacing="20">

                <Label Text="FAQ"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       TextColor="Gray" />

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout> 
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap your MasterDetailPage content inside a nested Grid, the Image and the Content will overlap eachother, creating the Backgound effect you are looking for

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu" BackgroundColor="White"
                 Icon="hamburger.png">
        <Grid>
            <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Image Source="background.png" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                //Your MasterDetailPage content
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out, you have to set your background color as transparent to set a background image. The trick worked for me, hope it works for you as well

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu"
          BackgroundColor="Transparent"
          BackgroundImage="hamburger.png">
        //Your xaml
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Comment: it worked fine for me, i uses this from a long time, idk why it didnt worked for you

Comment: BackgroundImage is obsolete, comments are <!-- --> in xaml/xml.